# Generating routes with polymorphic_url in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've got some problems with generating routes with polymorphic_url

Here is a part of my route.rb file :

```
scope path: '/my-account', controller: 'customers/base', as: :customer do
  ...
  resources :addresses, path: 'my-addresses'
  ...
end
```

rakes routes | grep addresses give me exactly the route i want :

```
customer_addresses GET      /:locale/my-account/my-addresses(.:format)
```

Now, if i use

```
send('customer_addresses_path)
```

in a link_to, all work fine.

But if i'm not able to generate the same url with polymorphic url :

```
app.polymorphic_path([:customer,:addresses])
#ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"addresses"}

app.polymorphic_path([Customer,:addresses])
#"/Customer/my-account/my-addresses" Not the same url :'(

app.polymorphic_path([Customer.first,:addresses])
#"/1/my-account/my-addresses" Not the same url :'(
```

Is there a way to use polymorphic_url to generate my url?

Answer (score 0):

Asking a question is a good way to reflect on it.

Solution here:

```
app.polymorphic_path([:customer,:addresses], locale: :en)
```